# How to add the service mark (SM) symbol in SharePoint 2010 web parts

Tags: 2010, special-characters

I can add the trademark (TM) symbol in SharePoint no problem however even the HTML version of the service mark (SM) symbol (℠) doesn't display. All I get is the invalid character box. I'm trying to input it in a few places, namely a blog post or in a Content Editor web part (via HTML). Unfortunately this is a requirement right now for a certain product name so there's no way of avoiding it. Suggestions?

Comment: As a workaround you can try to add image of the mark if you could not find another solution

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is more than one way to skin a service mark.

Using HTML in a non-semantic way, you can just use the  tag to include it.

```
<sup>SM</sup>
```